# И(и)ркутский епископ

Tags: прописная-строчная

С "епископом Иркутским" всё понятно, епископ пишется со строчной буквы, Иркутский - с прописной. А когда в тексте появляется "иркутский епископ"?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, в этом случае прилагательное надо писать со строчной буквы - "иркутский епископ". Фраза приобрела значение ЕПИСКОП ИЗ ИРКУТСКА (ср.: епископ из Москвы - московский епископ и т.д.). Это свободное словосочетание. А "епископ Иркутский" - несвободное, так как в этом случае слово Иркутский обретает значение имени.

http://www.doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.2:
С прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме служебных и местоимений, в наименованиях ***высших*** ***должностных лиц церкви***, например: 
Святейший Патриарх Московский и всея Руси, Местоблюститель Патриаршего Престола, Папа Римский. 
Наименования **других должностей и званий** пишутся со **строчной** буквы, например: 
митрополит Волоколамский и Юрьевский, архимандрит Евгений, отец Алексий, игумен Петр.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже склонялась к тому, что "иркутский" скорее указывает на местность, а не входит в наименование.

Comment: Спасибо за хороший вопрос.)))

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле - вопрос почти ни о чем.
Официальное название должности владыки Вадима - **Архиепископ Иркутский и Ангарский**.
Всё остальное - от лукавого и может писаться какими угодно буквами, хоть на китайском, к правилам написания должностей и званий это отношения не имеет.